Different multimeters give massively different resistance readings when measuring between HV+ and HV- on a hybrid car. Why is this?
I work on cars and we have had many cases of a fault with HV precharging time.
We are instructed to deactivate the HV system and perform a resistance measurement between HV positive and HV negative on isolated parts of the circuit using a standard multimeter until we find the faulty part (its always the same part but that's not the point here).
We observe the waiting time of 3 minutes (I assume we are measuring across capacitors in the HV components) but we get wildly different readings depending on whose multimeter we use (all calibrated regularly, though all different models), and on the same meters depending on the range selected.
One reads a dead short on the car unless set to manual ohms where it reads over limit but accurately measures resistors of all sizes.
Others change their readings depending on the range and whether they were auto ranged while connected to the test points or not.
So we might see 0.00 or 1.2 kohms, or 140 kohms, or 4.1 Mohms depending on the meter and the process.
Can anybody shed any light on what we are doing wrong and help me understand why this is happening?
Thanks.

If possible, change ohmmeter scales manually (turn off autoranging). If you see two adjacent scales agree, have more confidence that the resistance measured is meaningful. Measuring resistance in-situ is often meaningless due to inductors, capacitors or diodes also attached to measuring nodes.

Yes, you can't use a multimeter to measure resistance of something that isn't a resistance.
Any other component will affect the measurement and the result of the measurement.
The multimeter injects a small amount of current or voltage to try measure the other and calculate the resistance.
For example, if there is some amount of capacitance between the measurement points, it takes time for the capacitance to charge to the voltage there is supposed to be over a pure resistor, and the multimeter considers there is a short circuit or changing resistance until things settle.
But things may never settle if autoranging multimeter adjusts the range so the range change will change the voltage and again the capacitance needs to charge or discharge to the new setpoint, but it again sees higher or lower voltage due to the capacitance keeping charge.
There may be other components than capacitance as well, such as semiconductors.
For example if you take a simple LED diode, it will always have roughly the same voltage over it, regardless of current through it.
So if you take a multimeter and try to measure the LED in resistance mode, the LED voltage is same on all injected current ranges, so the multimeter simply calculates resistance based on voltage and current, and gets a wrong result because the LED voltage does not behave like resistor voltage.
Also, different multimeters measure the resistance with different currents, voltages, impedances etc. It is thus expected that different meters give a different result. And measurements are thus affected by the amount of small leakage currents.

I think my multimeter uses 200mV full scale and varies the current for each range, this would explain why I have so much trouble measuring the resistance of transformers.
